How to edit or hide (only some) crosshair tooltip for eCharts graphs
Is there a way in eCharts (JavaScript) for formatting or hiding the small tooltips that appear on the edge (for the crosshair type: tooltip.axisPointer.type cross)?
See this image.
I'm refering to the tooltip on the side of the y axis on this graph:
Minimal reproducible example
This is to see the tooltip when you hover over the graph on your left side


var chartDom = document.getElementById('chart');
var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
var option;

option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 266],
      type: 'line'
    },
    {
      data: [50, 23, 142, 2, 11, 5, 250],
      type: 'line'
    }
  ],
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    axisPointer: {
      //crosshair
      type: 'cross' // 'cross', 'line', 'shadow', 'none'
    }
  }
};

option && myChart.setOption(option);
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.5.1/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart" style="width: 100%; height:250px;"></div>



Other way to see it, created on the official echarts site
How to hide it (and leave active the x one)?
And, also, how to modify the content (as the formatter does in the main tooltip)?

Currently on my phone and cant try it out. But maybe axisPointer.label.formatter can be used to identify the axis and return '' on yAxis.

@Matthias Mertens So ok for the second thing. I have to try the formatter before to say it's good (but hadn't seen it so it might be possible). But leave your phone and try to hide completely the yaxis tooltip. It would be nicer if instead of returning `` what is not needed was put aside.
